# Regaining access to Ubuntu install in new personal computer (with old SSD)

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, boot, grub

I have a dual operating system on my personal computer (Lenovo) - Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

The hardware is set up to show a grub menu at the start - with Ubuntu set up as the default option.

Recently, I discarded this machine and shifted to a new one (Dell).

I took out the SSD hard drive from the old set up and put it into this new machine.

But now, the grub menu doesn't show up, and I boot up straight into Windows 10. The Ubuntu 16.04 LTS installation seems intact in the disk partition.

How do I boot this machine with Ubuntu, instead of Windows?

Comment: Newer Intel/AMD equipment rarely supports CSM.  Does this new machine support it? Without understanding the configuration of the original hardware it’s difficult to answer this question

Comment: @Ramhound: the "new" machine is actually a Dell Latitude 3450 core i5-5200u. The "old" machine was a Lenovo Flex 3 core i7-6500u (6th generation). Both machines are pretty old. What's the best way to check compatibility?